# null checking with traditional finally block for closing resources

Tags: java

There are examples on the net checking `null` before invoking `close()` for open resource.

```java
final InputStream in = ...; // may throw IOException
try {
    // do something.
} finally {
    if (in != null) { // this is really required?
        in.close();
    }
}
```

I've been always done without `null-checking-if`.

```java
final InputStream in = ...; // may throw IOException
try {                  // when it reached to this line 'in' is never null, could it be?
    // do something.
} finally {
    in.close(); // no null check required, am i wrong?
}
```

Comment: If you're going to "catch" `IOException`, you should be putting the assignment in a `try` block, shouldn't you?

Comment: @JinKwon what is the meaning of using `...` , is it just to short the typing or is it a keyword in java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is no chance of the resource becoming `null` in any of the code execution paths there's zero need for the null check.

You are doing the right thing.

Answer (score 1):

```
final InputStream in = ...;
```

The `...` possibly may return `null`, which is why there is a check.

Comment: what is the meaning of using `...` , is it just to short the typing or is it a keyword in java

Answer (score 1):

InputStream implements AutoClosable so you can use a [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement. Then you do not have to deal with the null as Java does this for you.

```
try (InputStream in = ...) {
    [some code]
}
```

Comment: Good catch. Mate!